# Can I use Google AdSense without Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, adsense

I created a blog and a CMS for blog's admin. The CMS has it all that admin needs: views, geolocation, subscribers, etc, so I don't really need Google Analytics anymore.

What we do need is to monetise the website and we want to use Google AdSense for that and now comes the question:

If I implement AdSense, will it be able to count my views without using Analytics? Do I need to prove AdSense the number of my views somehow? If so, than how should I, if I don't use Analytics?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programing related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads-up I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, AdSense has its own interface with its own reports, it is independent from Analytics. However it indicates the number of views and interactions with the ads on your site, for sure it is neither a comparable nor a replacement tool for Anlaytics.